# creating xml tree from a textfile with Python

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I need to avoid creating double branches in an xml tree when parsing a text file. Let's say the textfile is as follows (the order of lines is random):

branch1:branch11:message11
branch1:branch12:message12
branch2:branch21:message21
branch2:branch22:message22

So the resulting xml tree should have a root with two branches. Both of those branches have two subbranches. The Python code I use to parse this textfile is as follows:

```
import string
fh = open ('xmlbasic.txt', 'r')
allLines = fh.readlines()
fh.close()
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
root = ET.Element('root')

for line in allLines:
   tempv = line.split(':')
   branch1 = ET.SubElement(root, tempv[0])
   branch2 = ET.SubElement(branch1, tempv[1])
   branch2.text = tempv[2]

tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
tree.write('xmlbasictree.xml')
```

The problem with this code is, that a branch in xml tree is created with each line from the textfile.

Any suggestions how to avoid creating another branch in xml tree if a branch with this name exists already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open("xmlbasic.txt") as lines_file:
    lines = lines_file.read()

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.Element('root')

for line in lines:
    head, subhead, tail = line.split(":")

    head_branch = root.find(head)
    if not head_branch:
        head_branch = ET.SubElement(root, head)

    subhead_branch = head_branch.find(subhead)
    if not subhead_branch:
        subhead_branch = ET.SubElement(branch1, subhead)

    subhead_branch.text = tail

tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
ET.dump(tree)
```

The logic is simple -- you already stated it in your question! You merely need to check whether a branch already exists in the tree before creating it.

Note that this is likely inefficient, since you are searching up to the entire tree for each line. This is because `ElementTree` is not designed for uniqueness.

---

If you require speed (which you may not, especially for smallish trees!), a more efficient way would be to use a `defaultdict` to store the tree structure before converting it to an `ElementTree`.

```
import collections
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

with open("xmlbasic.txt") as lines_file:
    lines = lines_file.read()

root_dict = collections.defaultdict( dict )
for line in lines:
    head, subhead, tail = line.split(":")
    root_dict[head][subhead] = tail

root = ET.Element('root')
for head, branch in root_dict.items():
    head_element = ET.SubElement(root, head)
    for subhead, tail in branch.items():
        ET.SubElement(head_element,subhead).text = tail

tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
ET.dump(tree)
```

Comment: Thanks, this and also other answers work fine, but I'll stick to defaultdict as in reality the text and xml files be rather big.

Answer (score 0):

something along these lines? You keep the level of the branches to be reused in a dict.

```
b1map = {}

for line in allLines:
   tempv = line.split(':')
   branch1 = b1map.get(tempv[0])
   if branch1 is None:
       branch1 = b1map[tempv[0]] = ET.SubElement(root, tempv[0])
   branch2 = ET.SubElement(branch1, tempv[1])
   branch2.text = tempv[2]
```